# How can i launch a new UICollectionViewController from UIView?

Tags: ios

I have a login page with `UIView`. I want to launch an `UICollectionViewController` from a button click event.
I am using this line of code and `UICollectionViewController` is launched:

```
[self addSubview:menuViewController.view];
```

But it seems that this is the UI part of the previous UI and I want to launch a new window. How can I?

One more thing, i want a back button on `ControllerView`. I found some line for the same but the button is not visible.

Thanks

Comment: Navigate to the new Viewcontroller .and use collectionview controller there.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial on how use `UINavigationController` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reVzUBCS0sw

Comment: Hi Bhumika,
Can you tell me please some line of code for this? I am doing all dynamically. Actually My Login class inherits UIView class that does not provide any pushViewController so that i can launch.
thanks

Comment: HI BoilingLime,
I think this is the static approach to achieve this but i want to do it dynamically.
Thanks